# Ant with apostrophe replace

Tags: regex, search, ant, replace, apostrophe

I want to replace

```
from expression="ora:processXSLT('Transformation_1.xsl',bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload'))
```

to

```
from expression="ora:processXSLT('xsd/Transformation_1.xsl',bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload'))
```

Could any one suggest to me pattern a to choose?

I have tried:

```
<replaceregexp  flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="ora:processXSLT("/>
        <substitution expression="ora:processXSLT('xsd\1)"/> 
    <fileset dir="${fmw.prop}" includes="*"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<replaceregexp  flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="([^']+')(.*)"/>
        <substitution expression="\1xsd/\2)"/> 
    <fileset dir="${fmw.prop}" includes="*"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

In your regex, you are misusing `\1`. When you write a regex, everything you place between parenthesis is captured and then can be reinjected with `\1`. If there is more parenthesis groups, their content can be reinjected too using `\2`, `\3`, and so on. That means that when you want to match a real parenthesis, e.g. the `(` in `ora:processXSLT(`, you need to escape it like so: `\(`. That way it does not become a capturing parenthesis but is integrated into the matching pattern.

Furthermore, you need to capture and reinject everything you want to have in the final substitution, so you need to match the entire string, make your modifications, and return the newly formed string. That is why we are matching `ora:processXSLT('` with `[^']+'`, matching `Transformation_1.xsl',bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload'))` with `(.*)`, and placing `xsd/` in between both strings to obtain the proper result.

Comment: Thanks a million for quick help

Answer (score 0):

You should escape all regular expression control characters. Therefore your pattern should be something like:

```
ora\:processXSLT\('
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Bw3Ctr1OA2GHJA3-)

Your target should be

```
ora:processXSLT('xsd/
```

If understand your question right, this is a simple literal to literal replacement. So there is no need for group processing.